# Free editor for Ruby similar to Rubymine?

Tags: windows-7, gui, ide, ruby

I am having serious trouble finding working editors for Ruby on Windows 7 that aren't DOS based. Does anyone know of any that work like Visual Studio or Rubymine that are also free? Or, at least, cheaper than Rubymine?

What I am after is a simple Ruby Compiler with:

- 'Test code' and 'compile for release' functions.
- Code highlighting
- Helpful debugging Documentation.
- Tutorials and examples that work!

(And preferably a file tree of some kind for programs)

Honestly, I am on the verge of totally giving up. I have tried installing several different programs and not one of them will let me compile even the most basic code examples. I'll just run through my problems with each:

Visual Community 2015 - no Ruby support. Couldn't make their tutorials for other languages work either.
RubyMine - Has everything I want, but the annual subscription is stupidly expensive. (And I don't want to go open source)

The two closest to what I want are:

Aptana - looks great and supposedly does everything, but there are multiple bugs on the home page and no documentation or tutorials for Ruby I can find. Requires a Flash plugin not bundled with Windows 7. Can't make anything compile.

Visual Studio Code - I installed several extensions but have no idea how to make them work or if they are even compatible. Some seem to require the installation of things I just can't find anywhere. The current extensions I have are: Code Runner (Is it a code tester?), Ruby, Ruby Language Colorization, ruby-rubocop (requires things?), Simple Ruby ERB, and vscode-ruby-ctags. At the moment, the only one I am sure is working is Ruby Language Colorization.

I'm also really unclear as to what all these command codes do, or where I'm supposed to type them in. Even RubyGems seems to require them, and I thought that was what I was supposed to type them into!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Okay, does that help? :)

Comment: Let's hear from the devs. It's longer now – but not being my area of proficiency, I cannot really tell :) Thanks for the update, though!

Comment: As with any software product, you'll need to read the accompanying docs to determine how to use an extension or if it is applicable for your use.  At a minimum, you should read the Visual Studio Docs to become familiar with using the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider taking a look at [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/d?utm_expid=101350005-35.Eg8306GUR6SersZwpBjURQ.3&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F), the newest Microsoft code editor.  It’s a cross platform editor that’s free, extensible, and customizable.  It supports many [code extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) including Ruby.

The [Ruby extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby) supports debugging and language colorization.

**Update**: Visual Studio Code has a built in debugger that works with loaded extensions.  The first time you debug, you'll need to set up a debug configuration.  It's actually a json file that defines what the debugger expects including any passed arguments.  Clicking the "gear" icon in the debugger pane will allow you to set up the configuration.

[image]

Comment: That sounds perfect! I can't find the debugger addon under extensions, however. Is it already included? Any suggestions on which Ruby addons I should install?

Comment: Umm, having problems with it... (see above)

Comment: @Hadashi - See my update above.